# How to smoothen (curve fitting) this image text in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, image-quality, image-editing

I have this image text which I was able to obtain from a low resolution jpg and then cleaned it out to this point, but now as can be seen in the pic it does not look smooth. I can't find the words I should use to google this and find out how to make the writing look more smoother. Whenever I search for smoothen, Google only shows me blurring options but blurring did not help.

[image]

The lines look so irregular. Is there a tool that can easily smoothen this out in GIMP? For example the "G" curve I want it to smoothen to average to a nice curve as in the process of [Curve Fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting).

[image]

Comment: I think it would be better if you moved to inkscape? But realistically ist not worth the hastle just draw the curves again.

Comment: alright! thank you. i guess that would be the only way then xd

Comment: You could downsample the image and then do a Trace Bitmap in Inkscape. Might have to fix some wonky paths manually though [see example](https://imgur.com/7mMnYRX)

Comment: thank you! i had a python script in blender python that would convert the image to a mesh and then i was able to smooth it out in blender xd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of actually redrawing the curves using a vector image editor, it's possible to get a decent enough result using Inkscape's trace bitmap function. The same would be possible in Adobe Illustrator using its trace function (but Illustrator isn't free).

Here's how I would do it.

1. In GIMP, rescale the image to make it much smaller - using *Image > Scale Image*. Scale it to about 800px wide, interpolation Linear. That will kind of even out all the hard anti-aliased pixels.

Something like this

[image]

2. Import this into Inkscape, Select it, and do *Path > Trace Bitmap* - use the settings shown below

[image]

3. The result is pretty smooth. You might want to tweak some of the curves, handles and nodes manually if you think something isn't quite right.

[image]

4. Finally recolour the traced vector by sampling from the original using the eyedropper.

[image]

Comment: wow! fantastic! thank you so much!